# C# CodeDom - Create new field within CodeMemberMethod

Tags: c#, methods, codedom

In order to "populate" a CodeDom class I can create a new `field` which allows me to generate *random* names for strings, bytes, etc. I then created a new method within my class via CodeDom but I am having a lot of trouble populating this method. I have found that I can use the `CodeSnippetStatement` method to add direct strings into the CodeDom method but I do not want to have to use direct strings. Is there some other way to populate a CodeDom method?

**Here is what I am using now:**

```
CodeMemberMethod method = new CodeMemberMethod();
method.name = "mainMethod";
method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;

// Here is where the code is added as a direct string:
method.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement("string myString = path.getTempPath();"));

myClass.Members.Add(method);
Namespaces.Types.Add(myClass);
```

Once again, I would like to know if there is a new method I could use to add data into a CodeDom method.

Thank you,
Evan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a field (which is a type member) to a method.  You can, however, add a local variable by using a `CodeVariableDeclarationStatement`.  For the various types of statements available for use in methods, see the inheritance hierarchy of CodeStatement at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codestatement#inheritanceContinued.